# Computing the mean based on ID and condition

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

Here is my dataframe:

```
       ID  Tell  Number 
0       1   Yes     3   
1       1   Yes     6
2       1   No      9
3       2   Yes     4
4       2   Yes     7
5       2   No      8
6       3   Yes     15
7       3   Yes     8
8       3   No      6
9       3   Yes     13

# Creating the dictionary
dic = {'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], 'Tell': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes','Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes','No', 'Yes'], 'Number': [3,6,9,4,7,8,15,8,6,13]}

# Creating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

I want to create a 4th column that gives me the mean for each ID. The row is used in the calculation of the mean only if the Tell column is Yes.

So, my resultant df should look like this:

```
       ID  Tell  Number mean
0       1   Yes     3    4.5
1       1   Yes     6    4.5
2       1   No      9    4.5
3       2   Yes     4    5.5
4       2   Yes     7    5.5
5       2   No      8    5.5
6       3   Yes     15   12
7       3   Yes     8    12
8       3   No      6    12
9       3   Yes     13   12
```

I'm thinking about doing a groupby on my ID column, then checking if there is a Yes or No present in the Tell column. I'm not sure how to implement this.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# Creating the dictionary
dic = {'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], 'Tell': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes','Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes','No', 'Yes'], 'Number': [3,6,9,4,7,8,15,8,6,13]}

# Creating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

df = (pd.merge(left=df, right=df[df.Tell == 'Yes'].groupby('ID')['Number'].mean(), on='ID')
        .rename(columns={'Number_x':'Number', 'Number_y':'mean'}))

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID Tell  Number  mean
0   1  Yes       3   4.5
1   1  Yes       6   4.5
2   1   No       9   4.5
3   2  Yes       4   5.5
4   2  Yes       7   5.5
5   2   No       8   5.5
6   3  Yes      15  12.0
7   3  Yes       8  12.0
8   3   No       6  12.0
9   3  Yes      13  12.0
```

Comment: It gives me ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: @HueyGriffin I copied _exactly_ the same code from your question that creates the dataframe and the result is the same. See my updated answer. (Maybe reset Jupiter notebook is necessary?)